# # Firebase admin sdk 2.2.0 > I could send message yesterday it stopped working today with SSL connection timeout error

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, firebase-cloud-messaging, ssl-certificate, timeout

C# Dot Net 5 (core) console application: Firebase admin sdk  2.2.0.
I was working perfectly fine yesterday and started throwing exception today.
It looks like OAuth2 endpoint is not responding or not found.

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unknown error while making a remote service call: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)
 ---> FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Unknown error while making a remote service call: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<FillHandshakeBufferAsync>g__InternalFillHandshakeBufferAsync|182_0[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adap, ValueTask`1 task, Int32 minSize)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.TokenRequestExtenstions.ExecuteAsync(TokenRequest request, HttpClient httpClient, String tokenServerUrl, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IClock clock, ILogger logger)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.RefreshTokenAsync()
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.ResultWithUnwrappedExceptions[T](Task`1 task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.<>c.<GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync>b__10_0(Task`1 task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
   --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(String authUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceCredential.GetAccessTokenWithHeadersForRequestAsync(String authUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceCredential.InterceptAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.CredentialInterceptAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Util.ErrorHandlingHttpClient`1.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Util.ErrorHandlingHttpClient`1.SendAndReadAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at FirebaseAdmin.Util.ErrorHandlingHttpClient`1.SendAndReadAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Util.ErrorHandlingHttpClient`1.SendAndDeserializeAsync[TResult](HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessagingClient.SendAsync(Message message, Boolean dryRun, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.SendAsync(Message message, Boolean dryRun, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.SendAsync(Message message, Boolean dryRun)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.SendAsync(Message message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Formatted by https://st.elmah.io
```

Comment: Appears to be a connectivity issue.  I'd look at confirming if the OAuth url is accessible from a browser.

Comment: Thank you @LegendaryCopyCoder

I have 2 urls in my private key json file.

`
{
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
}
`

When I try to open auth_uri in my browswer, I get 401. I am assuming, it is fine because, I can reach it.
When I try to open token_uri in my browswer, I get "site can't be reached". I should have issue.

Any thoughts on it?

Comment: This https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token times out. It works on my server in Australia. But it times on my PC in India.

Comment: Any valid http response is fine yes. We just need the server to respond with something. 
Regarding the error response you posted, did that happen when testing on your local network? If you test the app on your Australian server, does it run without an error?

Comment: Thank you @LegendaryCopyCoder.

It works without any issue on my Australian Server.
Yes. It does not work on my local pc.

Comment: I see. That's good news that its running on the Australian server. That likely means something on your local network is restricting access. Sometimes company or student networks have these restrictions and you need to contact the admin or service provider to unblock the domain to gain access again.